# Инструменты для написания web-интерфейса к существующему приложению на Python

Tags: python

Меня посетила идея написать web-интерфейс.

На выходе хочу получить следующий функционал:

1. Кнопочками исполнять shell-команды и получать вывод в окно.
2. При необходимости в томже окне хочу иметь доступ к командной строке сервера.
3. Хочу иметь возможность сохранения вывода какой-либо команды исполняемой ранее в файл, с последующей возможностью просмотра содержимого этого файла.

Сейчас использую python для написания скриптов, но хочется чего-то большего. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать и какие инструменты мне использовать для реализации моих хотелок?

В моем распоряжении есть сервер на linux и апач/апач+nginx при необходимости.

Comment: `flask` - попроще, `django` - побогаче

Comment: pyramid тоже неплох

Comment: [`jupyter`](http://jupyter.org/) позволяет терминал в браузере запустить (среди других вещей). Если готовые части не использовать, то задача достаточно трудоёмкая, если просто поверх голых веб-библиотек типа flask,bottle, etc писать (достаточно много логики на клиенте(javascript) и websocket в качестве транспорта (для отзывчивости)желателен—о последнем нужно специально заботиться из-за огранич wsgi-модели   (возможно лучше asyncio, twisted, tornado для постоянных соединений использовать: [вот пример, который произвольный скрипт интерактивно выполняет](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11729467/4279))